# why Jackson only format DateTime(joda time lib) to milliseconds

Tags: json, spring, jackson, jodatime

I want to use Jackson lib format DateTime joda to `dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss`, but it doesn't work.
I searched and found questions and answers on `stackoverflow.com`. I try using many answers. but it is still wrong.

It only formats to milliseconds.

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Joda-time hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

In `User` domain:

```
@Column(name="date_of_birth")
@NotEmpty   
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime dob;
```

In configuration file:

```
    @Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss");
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
//  objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    return converter;
}
```

Comment: Please, specify what doesn't work. Do you get an exception or simply the wrong output? What version of Spring do you use?

Comment: Hi  Ilya Novoseltsev, my code no have exception. It only format to milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing this following method to register it to the message converter:

```
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried other date objects? e.g. LocalDate or even java.sql.Date? DOB doesn't need time or time zone, right?